# tf.train.import_meta_graph('model.meta') cannot handle seq2seq models with attention?

Tags: python, tensorflow, sequence

Environment:
Ubuntu 16.04;
TensorFlow v1.0.0 (CPU)

When attempting to import a saved graph using "tf.train.import_meta_graph('model.meta')," I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test_load.py", line 19, in new_saver = 
tf.train.import_meta_graph('model.meta') 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", 
line 1577, in import_meta_graph **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/meta_graph.py", 
line 498, in import_scoped_meta_graph producer_op_list=producer_op_list)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", 
line 259, in import_graph_def 
raise ValueError('No op named %s in defined operations.' % node.op)
ValueError: No op named attn_add_fun_f32f32f32 in defined operations.
```

This error isn't thrown when I retrain my model **without attention** and import the graph with the same line of code.
Is loading a model trained with attention not currently supported? Here is what my attention implementation looks like:

```
attention_states = tf.transpose(self.encoder_outputs, [1, 0, 2])

(attention_keys,
 attention_values,
 attention_score_fn,
 attention_construct_fn) = seq2seq.prepare_attention(
            attention_states = attention_states,
            attention_option = "bahdanau",
            num_units         = self.decoder_cell.output_size)

 decoder_fn_train = seq2seq.attention_decoder_fn_train(
            encoder_state          = self.encoder_state,
            attention_keys         = attention_keys,
            attention_values       = attention_values,
            attention_score_fn     = attention_score_fn,
            attention_construct_fn = attention_construct_fn,
            name                   = 'attention_decoder')

decoder_fn_inference = seq2seq.attention_decoder_fn_inference(
            output_fn              = output_fn,
            encoder_state          = self.encoder_state,
            attention_keys         = attention_keys,
            attention_values       = attention_values,
            attention_score_fn     = attention_score_fn,
            attention_construct_fn = attention_construct_fn,
            embeddings             = self.embedding_matrix,
            start_of_sequence_id   = self.EOS,
            end_of_sequence_id     = self.EOS,
            maximum_length         = tf.reduce_max(self.encoder_inputs_length) + 3,
            num_decoder_symbols    = self.vocab_size,)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Was the original saved graph (with attention) saved using an older TensorFlow version? It looks like things have moved around, which isn't super surprising for contrib.

Comment: No. I installed TF v1.0.0 and ran the training. It doesn't take long to train.

Comment: Sorry you ran into this. Could you check if a [recent change](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/00a294d68e0f36c44fefcf2e07bf40068250a884) fixes this for you? You'll need to build TensorFlow from source if you want to try it right away (the change was committed today).

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much! I appreciate your quick and excellent response.

Comment: Is `attention_decoder_fn` gone from master? because the fix above is in master but the attention decoder is only in r1.0. Anyone knows what is going on?

Comment: I've noticed the same thing.

Comment: @Gene How did you fix this issue? I am getting the same error, I am using TF v1.0.0